# System.PlatformNotSupportedException error in desktop App (.NET framework) VS2019

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am programing a BluetoothLE device. Same code works fine for console app.

But when I put that code into .NET framework, I get a runtime exception

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Windows Runtime (WinRT) is not supported on this platform.'

Both VS2019 and VS2022 have the same problem. However the same program works fine in VS2015.

This is the example I followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristic?view=winrt-22621

I tried to add `<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` in to the `.csproj`. But it does not help.

Comment: Does this help? - [Windows Runtime APIs not supported in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api) - _Some WinRT APIs were designed specifically for UI scenarios in a UWP app. Those APIs do not behave properly in desktop apps due to threading model and other platform differences_

Comment: This is not a problem with Visual Studio version, but probably a problem of .NET version or other dependencies. Your link doesn't point to a sample. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you are using a dll or a nuget that is compiled for WinRT only. and your app build configuration is x86